# Ruby regex- does gsub store what it matches?

Tags: ruby, regex, gsub

If i use

```
.gsub(/matchthisregex/,"replace_with_this")
```

does gsub store what it matches with the regex somewhere?  I'd like to use what it matches in my replacement string.  For example  something like

```
"replace_with_" + matchedregexstring + "this"
```

in my above example where the matchedregexstring would be the stored match from gsub?  Sorry if that was confusing, I don't know how else to word that.

Answer (score 36):

From the [fine manual](http://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-gsub):

> If *replacement* is a `String` it will be substituted for the matched text. It may contain back-references to the pattern’s capture groups of the form `\d`, where *d* is a group number, or `\k<n>`, where *n* is a group name. If it is a double-quoted string, both back-references must be preceded by an additional backslash. However, within *replacement* the special match variables, such as `&$`, will not refer to the current match.
>   [...]
>   In the block form, the current match string is passed in as a parameter, and variables such as `$1`, `$2`, $`, `$&`, and `$'` will be set appropriately. The value returned by the block will be substituted for the match on each call.

If you don't care about capture groups (i.e. things like `(expr)` in the regex) then you can use the block form and `$&`:

```
>> 'where is pancakes house?'.gsub(/is/) { "-#{$&}-" }
=> "where -is- pancakes house?"
```

If you do have capture groups then you can use `\n` in the replacement string:

```
>> 'where is pancakes house?'.gsub(/(is)/, '-\1-')
=> "where -is- pancakes house?"
```

or `$n` in the block:

```
>> 'where is pancakes house?'.gsub(/(is)/) { "-#{$1}-" }
=> "where -is- pancakes house?"
```

Comment: Aha! - so the extra `\` that appears in the docs are just artefacts from Rdoc. I’ve been scratching my head trying to figure out what they meant.

Comment: @matt: You mean the extra backslashes, right? #*&#$ Markdown, see my $-backtick variable for more fun like that :) Yeah, you need to say `\\1` if you use double quotes but `\1` is fine if you use single quotes (which I always do unless I need interpolation).

Comment: Yes, ```\``` not ``. I hadn’t noticed. I think comments could do with a preview sometimes.

Answer (score 6):

I found out [here](http://batsov.com/articles/2013/08/30/using-gsub-with-a-block/) that gsub's matches could actually be accessed through the `Regexp.last_match` variable (class [MatchData](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/MatchData.html#method-i-captures)) like this:

```
my_string.gsub(my_regexp){ Regexp.last_match.inspect }
```

To give a more practical example, if you want to log all matches, it may be used as follows:

```
"Hello world".gsub(/(\w+)/) { Regexp.last_match.captures.each{ |match| Rails.logger.info "FOUND: #{match}"} }

#Rails log:
FOUND: Hello
FOUND: world
```

In your specific case, you could do something like this:

```
mystring.gsub(/(matchthisregex)/){ mystring = "replace_with_#{Regexp.last_match[0].to_s}this"}
```

Answer (score 5):

For all ruby versions: Simple way to get matched string.

```
.gsub(/matched_sym/) {|sym| "-#{sym}-"}
```